# Define strange operators

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I' looking for a symbol rendering the connected sum of $n$ topological spaces (or other quite strange topological operations) in a "product-like" manner... What For example in writing

```
$$
{\Large{*}}_{i=1}^n G_i
$$
```

for the free product of n groups. How can I render this with the # operation in topological spaces? (Yes, I'm studying Hatcher's AT...)

**Edit:** *(Some mind-reading clarification by Willie)*

The OP is not asking about how to use the `*` or `\ast` symbols, if I read him correctly. He is asking the following question:

> How to define a (possibly variable size) math operator like `\sum` and `\prod` where the operator symbol is the octothorpe `#`, such that for in-line maths the upper and lower limits follow next to the symbol, and in `\displaystyle` with the upper and lower limits above and below the symbol?

This seems to be the referred part of Hatcher’s AG:

[image: definition from Hatcher]

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied some information on what the result should look like. Should we assume you mean a star as used on the third math line under "Presentation" here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\mathop{..}` command from amsmath makes its argument behave like a "large operator".

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{relsize}

 \newcommand{\bigstar}{\mathop{\Huge \mathlarger{\mathlarger{*}}}}

 \begin{document}

 Display:

 \[ \bigstar_{x}^{y} \]

 Inline: \( \bigstar_{x}^{y}\)


 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathop` is a TeX primitive, not a amsmath command.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm not sure why I thought that... perhaps I learned about it from the AMS math manual or something like that.

Comment: @frabjous -- two points: `\mathop` is indeed a primitive; it's *used* by `amsmath` (actually, `amsopn`) in the definition of `\DeclareMathOperator`.  and the symbol shown in the edit to the question is `\sharp`, not a star.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if the below code does what you want. At first I had the [relsize](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package in mind, but it scaled the asterisk not big enough. So I come up with a possible solution that uses the [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package to do the job. The new operator needs at least [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (in this case loaded by [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) for its declaration.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\name}{\raisebox{-0.6ex}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\ast$}}}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \name_{i=1}^n G_i
  \]
\end{document}
```

Since I didn't know how you want to call the new operator, I simply chose a trivial name. Rename as you like.

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP wants the `#` symbol instead of the `\ast`. Otherwise your answer is probably what he is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You have some good answers for the procedure.  The connected-sum symbol can be found in the `mathabx` package as `\hash` or `\varhash`.  See [“How to look up a math symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol).

Comment: Detexifiy doesn't give me neither \hash nor \varhash, but I am very grateful to everybody

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: I didn't use detexify either.  I just opened the symbols-letter.pdf and searched for "hash".  At times I've just paged through it, too.

Answer (score 2):

How about `\#`? I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `\ast`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\connectedsum{\ensuremath{\,\ast_{i=1}^n}\,}

\begin{document}

    $F_i\connectedsum G_i$

\end{document}
```