# Big asterisk "\bigast" symbol

Tags: symbols

How do I make a math-mode asterisk that works like sum or product operator?  (To represent the convolution.)

Comment: This question might help: »[Define strange operators](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5042)«.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: Thanks, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest would be to use `\Asterisk` from the `mathabx` package, and also the `\coAsterisk` (not sure what the differences are as they look identical to me).

Alternatively, you could use `\scalebox` from [the graphicx package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to re-size the standard `\ast` to suit.  Here is a comparison of these three (`\Conv` is the custom version) showing the behavior in inline and display mode with indices:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Conv}{\mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\ast$}}}}%
\begin{document}
{\small\verb|\Asterisk| \verb|\coAsterisk | \verb| \Conv|}

\hspace{0.35cm}% to simply comparrison
$
    f \Asterisk^{a}_{b}   g \qquad 
    f \coAsterisk^{a}_{b} g \qquad 
    f \Conv^{a}_{b}       g
$

\[
    f \Asterisk^{a}_{b}   g \qquad 
    f \coAsterisk^{a}_{b} g \qquad 
    f \Conv^{a}_{b}       g
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will it work like a "sum" operator that puts the indicies below and above the symbol?

Comment: In that case you can use `\mathop`. How do you want this to be shown in display mode and inline mode?

Comment: I was only using display mode.  Will it do as "sum" does in inline mode?

Comment: Is there a trick that is looks like a tabluar, or just a luck that it looks like matrix 3x3 ? I can't see any tabular or matrix in your code, could you explain the trick ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Nope, I am not that much of a genius. I used `\hspace{0.35cm}' to get the inline math to align with the display math, and the `\qquad` is just about the right size to align them. So it just looks almost like a table.

Comment: Thanks Peter. As I am learning LaTeX I get ensured, there there are so plenty of possibilities, that you never know all of it and may miss sth :). Even thou, nicely aligned example with low effort - clear code is important for educative purposes, your is for sure. All Best, Greg

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Thanks for the complement. I think I originally thought about doing a table, but then when I saw that the output looked reasonable enough as is, I decided not to.  You're definitely at the right place to learn -- I've learned almost everything I know about TeX from this site. BTW, I still consider myself at the advanced beginner level, even though my rep may make you believe otherwise, so feel free to ask more questions. I certainly wish I had asked more when I started making my choices on how to do things as it would have saved a lot of grief later.

Comment: The difference: the coasterisk is rotated by 30 degrees.

Comment: @Egbert: Wow, can't belive I never noticed that. Thanks for pointing that out.