# Misalignment in custom big symbol using mathop

Tags: horizontal-alignment, symbols

Following the advice of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41186/big-asterisk-bigast-symbol) question, I created the \itsep symbol:

```
\newcommand{\itsep}{\mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\circledast$}}}}
```

When used with single character sub/super-scripts, it displays properly, like this:

```
a \itsep^f_{g} b
```

[image: correct output]

If I place multiple characters in the sub-script the symbol behaves incorrectly:

```
a \itsep^f_{g \, a \, b} b
```

[image: incorrect output]

Is there a way to make this symbol truly behave like \sum or \bigwedge where the "big" symbol is centered over the subscript and centered under the superscript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if, instead of using the basic `\mathop` you use `\DeclareMathOperator*` from `amsmath`, this "insulates" the result from its context:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\itsep}{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\circledast$}}}
```

thus

```
\[
a \itsep^f_{g} b \qquad a \itsep^f_{g \, a \, b} b 
\]
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For reference, [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides `\mathclap` which allows for zero-width centred overlap of math content, based on the size its used in:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\itsep}{\mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\circledast$}}}}
\[
a \itsep^f_{g} b \qquad a \itsep^f_{g \, a \, b} b \qquad a \itsep^f_{\mathclap{g \, a \, b}} b
\]
\end{document}​
```

It depends on your use case whether this would be a problem when having excessively long subscripts, which may extend into the horizontal domain of the "operands" a and b.

Comment: I've used \mathclap before and it certainly is an interesting solution to this problem (that I hadn't thought of), but it is my preference to simply make the symbol behave like other "big" symbols and only have to present a fix at the definition rather than fixing it at each instance as this mathclap solution does.