# Symbol for multiple convolution

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to type convolution of the same function `m` times:

```
$\underbrace{g \ast g \ast \ldots \ast g}_{m}$
```

but I am looking for some more compact for, something like sum or product of `m` functions. Do you know of something like that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Found $g^{\ast m}$  on Wikipedia.

Comment: Or look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41186/big-asterisk-bigast-symbol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a circled asterisk, `\circledast` from `amssymb`, and also create a custom symbol for convolution big operator for a different notation, like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Conv}{%
  \mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\circledast$}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
g_1 \circledast g_2 \circledast \cdots \circledast g_n=\Conv_{i=1}^{n} g_i
\]

\[
\underbrace{g \circledast g \circledast \cdots \circledast g}_{m}=g^{\circledast m}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have already made something like this, based on what I was told by others    \mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.7ex}{\makebox[0.5\width][r]{$\ast$}}}}\limits^{m}_{l=0}

Answer (score 3):

This seems compact enough:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \underbrace{g \ast g \ast\dots\ast g}_{m}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} g^{\ast m} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not dots instead of ldots?

Comment: @daleif: You're right. I didn't change the O.P.'s code since it was asked for a compact notation.