# Math operator resizing in autosized brackets

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to define a new command to format `\mathbb{E}` in the same way as `\sum` - same size in display/inline formulae, and same treatment of sub/superscripts. The following seems to work...

```
\newcommand*{\bbe}{%
   \ifinner
      \mathbb{E}%
   \else
      \mathop{\displaystyle\vcenter{\hbox{\huge$\mathbb{E}$}}}%
   \fi
}
```

...except that in display formulae, when inside automatically sized brackets (e.g. `\left( \bbe_x \right)`) it reverts to treating it as if it were in an inline formula (so smaller size, subscripts to the right not beneath).

I'm not sure what's causing this issue; any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the “code” button (with “{}” on it). As I did in my edit. Furthermore I cleaned you definition to make it more readable …

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5042/define-strange-operators

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\ifinner` test is not safe for this application. Indeed the conditional is true whenever TeX opens a new math list when it's already in math mode.

The following Plain TeX code shows this:

```
\def\x{\ifinner\message{inner}\else\message{outer}\fi}
$${\x}$$
```

will print `inner` in the log file. The same happens inside a `\left`-`\right` pair.

What you need is `\mathchoice`, which depends only on the current math style, which doesn't change in math sublists.

```
\newcommand*{\bbe}{%
  \mathop{
    \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\huge$\mathbb{E}$}}}
               {\kern0pt\mathbb{E}}
               {\kern0pt\mathbb{E}}
               {\kern0pt\mathbb{E}}
  }\displaylimits
}
```

Probably `\larger` from the `relsize` package is better for display style:

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand*{\bbe}{%
  \mathop{
    \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\larger[4]$\mathbb{E}$}}}
               {\kern0pt\mathbb{E}}
               {\kern0pt\mathbb{E}}
               {\kern0pt\mathbb{E}}
  }\displaylimits
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\ifinner` is the wrong sort of test here, you need `\mathchoice`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\xbbe#1#2{\hbox{#1$#2\mathbb{E}$}}
\def\bbe{\mathop{%
\mathchoice
{\xbbe\huge\displaystyle}%
{\xbbe{}\displaystyle}%
{\xbbe{}\scriptstyle}%
{\xbbe{}\scriptscriptstyle}%
}}

\begin{document}

$a \bbe_0^1 $

\[ \bbe_0^1 \qquad \frac{\bbe_0^1}{\bbe_0^1} \]

\end{document}
```