# How to use \ifinner to differentiate between text math and display math mode?

Tags: math-mode, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/is-there-a-test-for-the-different-styles-inside-maths-mode)

This is my first post here, so I can't promise to get all formatting right, but I'll try.

Consider the following macro:

```
\def\modes{{\bf \ifmmode\ifinner IM\else MM\fi\else TM\fi}}
```

According to both the 'TeXbook' and 'TeX for the Impatient' the `\ifinner` macro should 'True if TeX is in [...] (nondisplay) math mode [...]' (page 209 in the TeXbook). The 'TeX for the Impatient' does not print the braces surrounding 'nondisplay', so when writing in a document:

```
\modes - $\modes$
\[
   \modes
\]
```

I'm kind of expecting to get:

```
TM - IM
                 MM
```

However, the result is:

```
TM - IM
                 IM
```

I guess the TeXbook has slightly more authority, yet to me it sounds reasonable that indeed I should get the expected result. So I guess my question boils down to the following:
Am I misunderstanding the explanation of `\ifinner` in the TexBook

- if yes, then how to achieve the result I'm looking for?
- if no, what could be wrong then? Both pdfTeX and LaTeX produce this result, I'm running pdfTeX/LaTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 on Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53155/math-operator-resizing-in-autosized-brackets) that might help you. Actually `\ifinner` is true in a subformula.

Comment: Actually the TeXbook says that `\ifinner` is true in nondisplay math mode but *doesn't* say it's false in display math mode. TeX by Topic is wrong on p. 201 where it says that `\ifinner` is not true in display math mode.

Comment: Note that `\ifinner` is also true inside a tabular environment (`\halign`)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. In the end the question egreg pointed at, hinted at the right solution. In the end, what I wanted is a macro that would put `\left` and `\right` in front of (any) braces whenever the formula would appear in display math mode, but not elsewhere. The other question and answers made me realize that I would actually loose all control over braces, so I just created a macro that always scales, except when I call a 'starred' version. That way I'm more in control, which I like.