# fleqn option makes math internal mode (inner) not detected

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

The following MWE points out that, without `fleqn` class option, math internal mode is detected ("i" and "o") but, as soon as `fleqn` class option is enabled, this mode is not detected anymore ("i" and "i").

Do you see what's going on?

```
\documentclass
%[fleqn]
{article}
%
\newcommand{\test}{%
  \relax%
  \ifinner%
  i%
  \else%
  o%
  \fi%
}
%
\begin{document}    
$\test$
%
\begin{equation}
  \test
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifinner` has never been a good test for being in inline or display math.

Comment: With `fleqn` you have for `equation` something like `$\m@th\displaystyle \hskip\mathindent\bgroup...`.  Without `fleqn` you have plain `$$...`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Could you explicit?

Comment: @egreg I've seen `amsmath`'s `\if@display` is more reliable but strange anyway, at least for me :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé  Without `fleqn` you will end up in `$$...$$`, with `fleqn` you will end up in `$...$`. For more look at `article.cls` and `fleqn.clo`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53155/math-operator-resizing-in-autosized-brackets

Comment: in other words the inner detection is working, it is just that the answer is not what you expected. It's hard to find any use case where `\ifinner` is a useful test in math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ifinner` does not really test anything useful in math mode whether or not `fleqn` is used.

If you want to distinguish displaystyle then unfortunately you need to use `\mathchoice`.

The following produces `t` inline and `d` in display whether or not the `[fleqn]` option is used.

```
\documentclass
[fleqn]
{article}
%
\newcommand{\test}{%
\mathchoice
{\displaystyle d}%
{\textstyle t}%
{\scriptstyle s}%
{\scriptscriptstyle 2}%
}
%
\begin{document}    
$\test$
%
\begin{equation}
  \test
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If just `\displaystyle` vs *non* `\displaystyle` matters, isn't `amsmath`'s `\if@display` reliable?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé if you only use amsmath constructs and never `$$` or `eqnarray` or any other non-amsmath math construct then yes.