# Large \perp symbol and proper circled \perp symbol

Tags: symbols

Is there a command for a larger version of the symbol `\perp` used to denote perpendicularity? I have had a look at the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and didn't find a large version of this symbol.

Also, I would like to know whether the situation has changed since this question on [a symbol for orthogonal sum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61871/orthogonal-direct-sum) as asked. I find the `\obot` and `\bigobot` just don't do the job for me.

Comment: a circled perpendicular is in unicode at Ux2989, so it should be in the stix and xits fonts.  there's no large perpendicular, but if you can supply a reference showing it in a published document from a recognized publisher, i will be happy to submit it to unicode for consideration.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I can offer for a `\bigperp` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigperp}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\bigp@rp\relax}%
  \displaylimits
}

\newcommand{\bigp@rp}[2]{%
  \vcenter{
    \m@th\hbox{\scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle2.1\else1.5\fi}{$#1\perp$}}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle\bigperp\sum
\textstyle\bigperp\sum
\scriptstyle\bigperp\sum
\scriptscriptstyle\bigperp\sum
$

$\displaystyle\bigperp_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}$
\end{document}
```

[image]