# sign for multiple $\Diamond$-product

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I use `$\Diamond$` as a product sign and want to have something like `$\bigDiamond_{i=1}^{n}$` to note multiple `$\Diamond$`-products. Similar to `$\wedge$` and `$\bigwedge$` or `$\vee$` and `$\bigvee$`. Is there a package for this problem?

Comment: this need is addressed in [Define strange operators](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5042/579) and [How are big operators defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116506/579) also, welcome to the forum.

Comment: While the related questions are relevant, the answers don't really cover this particular case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For such a simple geometric symbol, scaling it seems the easiest road. You might want a larger factor than 1.2 for text style, adjust at will. However, 2 is the right scaling factor for display style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\bDiamond}{\mathbin{\Diamond}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bigDiamond{\mathop{\mathpalette\bigDi@mond\relax}}
\newcommand\bigDi@mond[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\m@th
    \scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 2\else1.2\fi}{$#1\Diamond$}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\bigoplus_{i=1}^n % just for comparison
\bigDiamond_{i=1}^n (a_i\bDiamond b_i)\quad
\textstyle\bigDiamond_{i=1}^n a_i\quad
\scriptstyle\bigDiamond_{i=1}^n a_i\quad
\scriptscriptstyle\bigDiamond_{i=1}^n a_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `\Diamond` for a binary operation or the spacing would be wrong; you need to use `\mathbin{\Diamond}`, which is what `\bDiamond` does.