# How to fill a symbol with a colour?

Tags: symbols

LaTeX symbols like `\diamond`, `\circ` and `\square` when compiled are in the form of symbols that are transparent. How can I fill black color into these shapes? For example, `\circ` shaded black is `\bullet`. Is there any command similar for `\diamond` and `\square`?

Comment: Please read : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem. Please also include a sketch how the output should look like.

Comment: There is a similar question on this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196782/filled-diamond-product-sign. Is it a duplicate your question?

Comment: The package `MnSymbol` provides the symbols `\filleddiamond` and `\filledmedsquare`. Many other packages have similar symbols. Consult the [comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Filled equivalent symbols are available. Once opened, this should be closed as a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Answer (score 4):

`amssymb` has them, otherwise, for example, you could use `fdsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
\noindent With \texttt{amsmath}:
\[
\blacklozenge \quad \blacksquare
\]
With \texttt{fdsymbol}:
\[
\medblackdiamond \quad \medblacksquare \quad
\smallblackdiamond \quad \smallblacksquare \quad
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*
Since `\nabla` is affected by `fdsymbol`, you could use `stix`, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily\textbackslash}l>{$}l<{$}}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{With \texttt{stix} package:}\\
        mdblkdiamond & \mdblkdiamond \\
        mdblksquare & \mdblksquare \\
        mdlgblkdiamond & \mdlgblkdiamond \\
        mdlgblksquare \textnormal{or its alias} \textbackslash\texttt{blackquare} & \mdlgblksquare \quad \blacksquare\\
        nabla \textnormal{is correct}& \nabla
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with the package fdymbol. In fdsymbol \nabla doesnot show the gradient operator instead it displays a big black circlw

Comment: @LeoLukose You could use `stix`, please look at the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An option for a simple staring point (the purpose of the symbols is not clear (e.g. math/text/graphics symbol?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\shadedraw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
  \tikz[rotate=45]\shadedraw (0, 0) rectangle ({1/sqrt(2)}, {1/sqrt(2)});
  \tikz[rotate=45]\shadedraw[shading angle=45]
    (0, 0) rectangle ({1/sqrt(2)}, {1/sqrt(2)});
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath}
\begin{document}
$\mdwhtcircle\mdblkcircle$
$\mdlgwhtdiamond\mdlgblkdiamond$
$\mdlgwhtsquare\mdlgblksquare$
\end{document}
```

[image]