# How to import a few symbols from `fdsymbol`?

Tags: fonts, packages

I saw this question: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) and I try to figure out how I do it for  `fdsymbol` to the symbols: `\neswarrow, \leftrightarrow, \nwsearrow, \updownarrow`

I can't load the  `fdsymbol` package because it's destroy some of the `amsmath` symbols :-(...

Can you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Probabily this question can help you to understand that fdsymbol burn any symbol of amsmath: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406760/how-to-fill-a-symbol-with-a-colour

Comment: The answer you need *is* in the question you cite.  The file you need to look at for the commands you need is `fdsymbol.sty`.  The sub-font containing the symbols you want is `arrows`,  You will need to copy the lines that are equivalent to the ones shown in the cited question, but for the `arrows` sub-font and the particular symbols.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - where? https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fdsymbol?lang=en can you help to find it here please?

Comment: If you are working on a system based on TeX Live, you should already have the file; check by typing `texdoc fdsymbol` at a command prompt.  If it's not there, you should be able to add it using the method for your installation; see the links here for a method appropriate for your system: [Installing, updating, restoring, other system operations](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2426/)

Comment: I'm working with LyX and TeXWorks, can you guide at those please?

Comment: @Sebastiano - so how can I solve it? How can I upload only one symbol??

Comment: @heblyx For my opinion  you need to pick up the symbols you need. If I remember correctly, there are already resolved issues (I've seen one recently) just to have a map of the specific symbols you need. But I am not an expert on this subject.  I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `fdsymbol.sty` there are no slot numbers and one has to count manually.

One finds

```latex
\fdsy@setslot{0}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\rightarrow}{arrows}{\mathrel}
```

which means `\rightarrow` is at slot 0 of the `arrows` symbol font. Looking for your desired symbol and counting yields that

- `\leftrightarrow` is at slot 16
- `\updownarrow` is at slot 17
- `\neswarrow` is at slot 18
- `\nwsearrow` is at slot 19

We also find

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows}{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}
```

Thus we need also to copy the font definitions for this font and undefine `\updownarrow`.

You may want to change the scaling value.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\def\fdsy@scale{1}
\newcommand\fdsy@mweight@normal{Book}
\newcommand\fdsy@mweight@small{Book}
\newcommand\fdsy@bweight@normal{Medium}
\newcommand\fdsy@bweight@small{Medium}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolC-\fdsy@mweight@small
    <7.1-> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolC-\fdsy@mweight@normal
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolC}{b}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolC-\fdsy@bweight@small
    <7.1-> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolC-\fdsy@bweight@normal
}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{fdarrows}{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{fdarrows}{bold}{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftrightarrow}{\mathrel}{fdarrows}{16}
\let\updownarrow\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\updownarrow}{\mathrel}{fdarrows}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\neswarrow}{\mathrel}{fdarrows}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nwsearrow}{\mathrel}{fdarrows}{19}

\begin{document}

$\leftrightarrow\updownarrow\neswarrow\nwsearrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]