# Does anyone know the name of this symbol?

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know the name of this rotated, filled in, black square symbol?

[image]

Comment: `\blackdiamond` (mathabx), `\filleddiamond` (MnSymbol), `\Diamondblack` (txfonts), `\FilledDiamondshape` (ifsym), `\FilledBigDiamondshape` (ifsym), `\DiamondSolid` (bbding)

Comment: See e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196792/117050

Comment: See http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: Another option using `amssymb` and `graphicx`: `\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}`

Comment: The `stix` fonts have this in several sizes: `\mdlgbkldiamond`, `\mdblkdiamond`, `\smblkdiamond`.  All are "ordinary" characters, but can be assigned another class.

Comment: ◆ is U+25C6, and available through `fontspec` and `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some packages (e.g., `txfonts`) change many symbols. One possibility is to use `amssymb` and rotate the `\blacksquare` symbol using `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package.

Depending on whether you're using the symbol as a relation, operation or ordinary symbol, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\blackdiam}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}}

\begin{document}

$a\blackdiam b$

$a\mathbin{\blackdiam}b$

$a\mathrel{\blackdiam}b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can include the `\mathbin` or `\mathrel` in the macro. You can also [use `\mathchoice` or `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette) so your symbol can be used in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`.