# Opposite product signs in the sense that black and white are interchanged

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

In a special algebra I use with `amssymb` the products

```
\newcommand{\bDiamond}{\mathbin{\Diamond}}
\newcommand{\bLozenge}{\mathbin{\blacklozenge}}
\newcommand{\bCircledast}{\mathbin{\circledast}}
\newcommand{\bOdot}{\mathbin{\odot}}
```

See also the two earlier answered questions [sign for multiple $\Diamond$-product](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186099/sign-for-multiple-diamond-product) and [Filled \Diamond-product sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196782/filled-diamond-product-sign). The two product signs `\bDiamond` and `\bLozenge` are opposite or partners in the sense that black and white are interchanged.

Now I would like to have

- a partner sign for `\bCircledast`, i.e. a white asterisk on a black disk (the shape should be the same as `\bCircledast`) and
- a partner sign for `\bOdot`, i.e. a white dot on a black disk (the shape should be the same as `\bOdot`)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Note that `\circledast` and `\odot` are already binary operation symbols, so `\mathbin` is not necessary for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Print a big black circle and overprint to it a white asterisk or a white dot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,color}

\newcommand{\invcircledast}{%
  \mathbin{\vphantom{\circledast}\text{%
    \ooalign{\smash{\blackcircle}\cr
             \hidewidth\smash{\textcolor{white}{$*$}}\hidewidth\cr
            }%
  }}%
}
\newcommand{\invodot}{%
  \mathbin{\vphantom{\odot}\text{%
    \ooalign{\smash{\blackcircle}\cr
             \hidewidth\smash{\whitedot}\hidewidth\cr
            }%
  }}%
}

\newcommand{\blackcircle}{\raisebox{-.4ex}{\scalebox{1.66}{$\bullet$}}}
\newcommand{\whitedot}{\raisebox{.4ex}{\textcolor{white}{\scalebox{.3}{$\bullet$}}}}

\begin{document}
$a\circledast b\invcircledast c$

$a\odot b\invodot c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to use the $\invcircledast$ sign as a multiple product sign with sub- and superscripts?

Comment: @HennerWild I think you're going to produce a not very nice document, if you use these symbols. ;-)

Comment: You are right; but it makes the notation more compact and much shorter.