# How to adjust self defined multiple product signs

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

The latex code below produces multiple product signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,color}

\newcommand{\invcircledast}{%
\mathbin{\vphantom{\circledast}\text{%
\ooalign{\smash{\blackcircle}\cr
         \hidewidth\smash{\textcolor{white}{$*$}}\hidewidth\cr
        }%
}}%
}
\newcommand{\blackcircle}{\raisebox{-.4ex}{\scalebox{1.66}{$\bullet$}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bigCircledast{\mathop{\mathpalette\b@gCircledast\relax}}
\newcommand\b@gCircledast[2]{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\m@th
\scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 2.3\else1.2\fi}{$#1\circledast$}%
}}%
}
\newcommand\bigInvcircledast{\mathop{\mathpalette\b@gInvcircledast\relax}}
\newcommand\b@gInvcircledast[2]{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\m@th
\scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 2.3\else1.2\fi}{$#1\invcircledast$}%
}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\bigoplus_{i=1}^n % just for comparison
\bigCircledast_{i=1}^n % just for comparison
\bigInvcircledast_{i=1}^n (a_i\invcircledast b_i)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

My question now is how to adjust the product signs `\bigCircledast` and `\bigInvcircledast` such that the disks have the same size as `\bigoplus` AND that the sub- and superscripts are on the same line as the sub- or the superscripts of `\bigoplus` respectively.

Compare also the questions and answers of [Opposite product signs in the sense that black and white are interchanged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196921/opposite-product-signs-in-the-sense-that-black-and-white-are-interchanged) and [Filled \Diamond-product sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196782/filled-diamond-product-sign).

Most of the ideas used in the code above came from [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg). See also the links above.

Comment: You can create your own `\bigCircledplus` by just copying the code for `\bigCircledast` are replacing `\circledast` by `\oplus`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution to this question:
[image] 
Essentially I added `\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{16pt}}}` at the end of the command definitions. The disadvantige of this solution is its dependence on the font size. For example, if one uses `\Huge` to enlarge the font size, the height of `\rule` needs to be adjusted to `40pt`.

The whole code of this solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,color}

\newcommand{\invcircledast}{%
\mathbin{\vphantom{\circledast}\text{%
\ooalign{\smash{\blackcircle}\cr
         \hidewidth\smash{\textcolor{white}{$*$}}\hidewidth\cr
        }%
}}%
}
\newcommand{\blackcircle}{\raisebox{-.4ex}{\scalebox{1.66}{$\bullet$}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bigCircledast{\mathop{\mathpalette\b@gCircledast\relax}}
\newcommand\b@gCircledast[2]{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\m@th
\scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 2.1\else1.2\fi}{$#1\circledast$}%
}}\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{16pt}}}%
}
\newcommand\bigInvcircledast{\mathop{\mathpalette\b@gInvcircledast\relax}}
\newcommand\b@gInvcircledast[2]{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\m@th
\scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 2.1\else1.2\fi}{$#1\invcircledast$}%
}}\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{16pt}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%\Huge
\[
\bigoplus_{i=1}^n % just for comparison
\bigCircledast_{i=1}^n
\bigInvcircledast_{i=1}^n (a_i\invcircledast b_i)
\]
\end{document}
```